# Ability to programmatically remove a Logger

Tags: log4net

Is there a way to remove a `Logger` once it has been added? Say via:

```
LogManager.GetLogger("loggerName")
```

In my research, it would appear it is not possible. The closest I have found is the ability to call the `Clear` [hierarchy method](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy.Clear.html). This will indeed clear out the existing loggers but I would like to selectively remove them, not to mention this likely isn't the safest thing to be doing.

For some background, I am logging one file per task where there could be potentially thousands of concurrent tasks and hundreds of thousands of tasks per application lifetime. One approach is to create a `Logger` for each task and then remove it once the task has completed. Without the ability to selectively remove a `Logger` though, memory will get chewed up by the retired instances.

Of course, there are alternative designs that would work. The problem could be addressed by adding/removing `Appenders` and `Filters` as necessary to a given `Logger`. Also, a pool of `Loggers` and `Appenders` could be created and then configured per task.

It obviously isn't a show stopper if there is no way to remove a specific logger once it is added. I'm just curious if there is a way to delete a `Logger` that I may have missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrapping this up since it has been open a long time.  I haven't found a way to remove a logger by itself and nothing I've seen in the documentation suggests it is possible either.  The solution that worked for me to share a pool of loggers that would only grow to the max amount of concurrent tasks.  Each task could take a logger from the pool with an appender added specific to that task.  On task completion, the appender is removed and the logger returned to the pool.

Answer (score 2):

No, it isn't possible. This is specifically mentioned in their FAQ these days:

**Logger instances seem to be create only. Why isn't there a method to remove logger instances?**
  It is quite nontrivial to define the semantics of a "removed" logger which is still referenced by the user.

Source:
[Ability to programmatically remove a Logger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13371277/ability-to-programmatically-remove-a-logger)